# Parse.com email verification link expiry

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, email-verification

I am using Parse.com for the user registration of my mobile application. Is there a way to set the length of time that the link sent by parse.com to the email of the user is only valid (e.g. the email verification link is only valid for 12 hours)? I can't see any such function on the dashboard of parse.com.

Comment: You can not put expiry on parse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about doing it on parse.com but since you'll have to migrate off of that anyway, here's some information about how they're supporting it in parse server:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/275

I just skimmed it so I'm not sure if there's enough detail to really implement it but maybe it will get you started when you're on parse server.